# view not updating using behaviorSubjects in Anguar project

Tags: angular, typescript, system.reactive

in my Angular project I'm getting data from an api using a service and I'm saving data inside a behaviorSubject like so

```js
  private categorySubject = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
  apiBehavior = new ReplaySubject<ApiResponseInterface>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) {}
  getQuestions(page: string = '', category = this.categorySubject.getValue()): Observable<ApiResponseInterface> {
    let url = this.baseUrl;
    if (category) {
      console.log(category);
      url = this.baseUrl + '/category/' + category;
    }
    const params = new HttpParams().set('cursor', page);
    return this.http.get<ApiResponseInterface>(url, { params })
      .pipe(tap((res) => this.apiBehavior.next(res)));
  }
```

in my component I'm subscribing to the behavior subject like so

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.questionsService.getQuestions()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.apiResponse = res;
        this.questions = res.data;
      });
  }
```

and everything's works fine until here, I have another component which passes a new value to the categoryBehaviorSubject inside the service with this function:

```js
setCategorySubject(categoryId: number | null) {
    this.questionsService.setCategory(categoryId);
  }
```

So the setCategory function inside my service passes the new value to the categotyBehaviorSubject and updates the apiBehavior like so:

```js
setCategory(categoryId: number | null) {
    this.categorySubject.next(categoryId);
    this.getQuestions();
  }
```

this is the template of my component that should show questions:

```html
<main
  *ngIf="questions"
  class="p-6 lg:p-20 flex max-md:flex-col gap-6 align-items-center h-full md:justify-between w-full"
>

  <section class="flex flex-col gap-6 align-items-center md:w-4/5 lg:w-2/5">
    <app-category-selector
      class="flex justify-center align-items-center mt-6 md:hidden"
    >
    </app-category-selector>
    <header class="font-primary text-bold text-lg text-center"><h1>{{questions.length}} Posts</h1></header>

    <app-question
      *ngFor="let question of questions"
      [question]="question"
      class="bg-secondary flex p-4 rounded h-1/4"
    ></app-question>
</main>
```

the problem here is: even tough the data is correctly fetched from the api and passed to the apiBehavior Subject the view is not updated and new questions are never displayed when a category has been set, what am I. doing wrong here?

Comment: Please update your question and show us how you are accessing the data in the view (show the code from the html file). Thanks

Comment: I think your issue is that after your pipe in `ngOnInit()` was executed for the first time, it automatically unsubscribes from the http-request-observable that was received from `getQuestions()`.

Comment: so what should I do to prevent that? is something I've done causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the setCategory function inside my service passes the new value to
> the categotyBehaviorSubject and updates the apiBehavior like so:

```
setCategory(categoryId: number | null) {
this.categorySubject.next(categoryId);
this.getQuestions(); // does NOT trigger the request
}
```

You said that "it updates the apiBehavior" - but this is wrong
Calling the function getQuestions() will not trigger another request, you can watch your Network tab from the inspector tools.

And since another request is NOT triggered, then the code from this pipe will not run either:

```
return this.http.get<ApiResponseInterface>(url, { params })
  .pipe(tap((res) => this.apiBehavior.next(res)));
```

Now, why another request is not triggered from getQuestions() is called from setCategory?

Because getQuestions() returns an Observable and nothing will happen until you subscribe to it.

You may say

> But I already subscribed to it inside ngOnInit

No, you subscribed to another Observable there. When the request is done, the Observable created by http client is marked as completed and it's simply gone. After the first request is over, calling getQuestions() will return another Observable and you need to subscribe to it too.

So your main take away is: calling this.http.get() without subscribing equals NO request. No request also implies that the pipe logic will never be executed.

If what I said so far is not clear enough, please take some time and read the following article:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Now, how can you fix your design?

I'm not sure if this is the optimal solution, BUT here is my idea:

create another EventEmitter, let's call it QuestionsObservable (maybe BehaviorSubject, I don't know which one would work better for you) and every time you request the questions, push the received data into QuestionsObservable.

Inside your component which displays the questions, subscribe to QuestionsObservable.

Give it a try and I'll answer if you have any more questions.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer I came up with a solution similar to the one you proposed, I created an observable with the asObservable() method on the apiBehavior and then I subscribed to it inside my component calling the refreshQuestions function immediately after, now component looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/JniBTLH5)
problem now is that when I click on load more... button the loadMore() function should fire and append new paginated results to the existing ones, but now results sort of override already present ones

Comment: If you are overriding the results, most likely you are entering wrongfully the if statement from line 22 (from your pastebin). Also, I don't really understand what's the point of line 15 in your paste bin. It seems that you are doing the same request 2 times in that ngOnInit, which does not look good (although this is not the reason why you are overriding the data). If I were you, I would debug this scenario with some console logs. It seems quiet easy to solve. Ask another question if you still cannot figure it out.